# Enumerate through variable (porting PyMC to PyMC3)

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I'm starting out with PyMC3 by translating [this code](http://stronginference.com/implementing-dirichlet-processes-for-bayesian-semi-parametric-models.html) from PyMC to PyMC3.

I'm not sure how to translate this segment:

```
v = pymc.Beta('v', alpha=1, beta=alpha, size=N_dp)
@pymc.deterministic
def p(v=v):
    """ Calculate Dirichlet probabilities """

    # Probabilities from betas
    # this line creates the error:
    value = [u*np.prod(1-v[:i]) for i,u in enumerate(v)]
    # Enforce sum to unity constraint
    value[-1] = 1-sum(value[:-1])

    return value

z = pymc.Categorical('z', p, size=len(set(counties)))
```

I assume I have to replace `p` in the last line with `p(v)` and remove the `@pymc.deterministic` but the problem seems to be that I cannot enumerate through `v`: `ValueError: length not known: ViewOp [id A] 'v'`.

Can someone show me how to do the translation or link me to the relevant bit in the documentation? Thanks.

Comment: For the interested, I found that I can create the variable `value` by making it out of `v` using a tensor instead of a list comprehension:

`def stick_breaking(beta): 
    portion_remaining = tt.concatenate([[1], tt.extra_ops.cumprod(1 - v) [:-1]]) 
    value = v * portion_remaining
    return value`

Answer (score 2):

The Dirichlet distribution is actually [built into `pymc3`](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/api/distributions/multivariate.html#pymc3.distributions.multivariate.Dirichlet), so that whole code block can be replaced by:

```
with pm.Model():
    ...
    v = pm.Beta('v', alpha=1, beta=alpha, shape=N_dp)
    p = pm.Dirichlet('p', a=v, shape=N_dp)
    ...
    trace = pm.sample(20000)
```

Comment: Hi JLLagrange - I think this won't work here as I'm doing the stick-breaking construction of the Dirichlet Process. Otherwise I'd have to use an infinite-dimensional Dirichlet.

Note that `p` has a Griffiths-Engen-McCloskey (GEM) distribution with parameters given by the Beta-distributed vector `v`.